# Connect R to a local Access database

Tags: r, odbc, ms-access-2007

I would have thought this would be simple but it definitely isnt.
I'm on windows 7 Pro, 64 bit. I have a Microsoft Access database 2007 (SP3). I would like to connect to a database I have from R.
I have downloaded and installed RODBC on R studio.

I have used the command as follows:

```
odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=G:/Current members of the lab/Seb/ProjectBEST2_RFA/MasterDatabase/BEST2RFA_DBv1.accdb")
```

I get an error message as follows:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=G:/Current members of the lab/Seb/ProjectBEST2_RFA/MasterDatabase/BEST2RFA_DBv1.accdb") :

[RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=G:/Current members of the lab/Seb/ProjectBEST2_RFA/MasterDatabase/BEST2RFA_DBv1.accdb") :
       ODBC connection failed
```

I tried changing the path name as follows:

```
    G:/Current\\members\\of\\the\\lab/Seb/ProjectBEST2_RFA/MasterDatabase/BEST2RFA_DBv1.accdb
```

but I still get the same error:

```
 1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=G:/Current\\members\\of\\the\\lab/Seb/ProjectBEST2_RFA/MasterDatabase/BEST2RFA_DBv1.accdb") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Comment: Are you sure you have 64-bit Access drivers?

Comment: How would I find that out. When I look at adding a new system DSN it only offers SQL native client and SQL server

Comment: Open up an Office application, then click File then Help (on the left hand side). The version number will tell you if you have 32-bit or 64-bit Office installed. If it is 32-bit, you will need to use 32-bit R to access.

Comment: OK. Tried that. I have Access 2007. There is no way to tell what bit system of Access I am using from the program (tried Access Options>Resources>About...      It just tells me the version and service pack. Google doesnt help either. Seems like no-one accesses what bit Access 2007 is.

Comment: OK, I have 2010 and it tells you there. The other option is to try replicating your analysis in 32-bit R. If it works, then you have 32-bit Access drivers.

Comment: So I have reinstalled R as 32 bit. I still get the same problem. I realised that perhaps I didnt have a DSN set up for the database. I have tried to create one using the odbcad32.exe program but it does not seem to least Access drivers. I think this is the central issue but googleing it doesnt seem to give me the answer. IS this now off topic and should I ask as a seperate question

Comment: OK. Now have sorted. This was painful. I had to repair my installation of Microsoft Access 2007 (don't worry the data seems to be maintained but I'd back it up anyway). This then allowed me to add my database as a DSN from odbcad32.exe in the Syswow64 folder. Having done that I managed to do a passwordless connect in R with channel <- odbcConnect("MyDSN", believeNRows=FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you should use Windows backslash ("\") instead of slash ("/"). And, spaces should be like "\ " instead of "\", which is printing the backslash character.

Comment: I tried moving the database to avoid the path spaces issue altogether and then did odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=G:\BEST2RFA_DBv1.accdb") but get the same error

Comment: @user3632206 You could try to specify the Id of the driver. Use **Control Panel** -> **AdministrativeTools** -> **ODBC Data Sources (32/64bit)** and create your own connection with the available drivers in the system.